Changing a server name for SQL Server replication
We have two servers set up for transactional replication and we need to migrate all of the content from one of the sides (the distributor) to another SQL Server instance.
Is there a way to change to server name for replication, or will the entire replication setup have to be redone?
Nothing has been tried yet - this is a configuration question

There are many operational scenarios that require you to set up replication again from scratch.  It might be wiser to exercise that runbook than to figure out a new one for this particular scenario.
